# Android Studio 3.1.2 - Can't run a C++ subroutine "No implementation found for Java.lang.String..."

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

My code compiles, but when I make the call to the C++ subroutine, the app dies with an UnsatisfiedLinkError.

In CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             src/main/cpp/crlTCheckkey.cpp)
```

In Tab1.java:

```
package com.labyrinthsys.crltext;

String statusString;
String keyPath;
            statusString = crlTCheckkey(keyPath);
...

public native String crlTCheckkey(String keyPath);
```

In crlTCheckkey.cpp:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring

JNICALL
Java_com_labyrinthsys_crltext_Tab1_crlTCheckkey(
    JNIEnv *env,
    jobject, /* this */
    jstring keyFilePath) {
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String com.labyrinthsys.crltext.Tab1.crlTCheckkey(java.lang.String) (tried Java_com_labyrinthsys_crltext_Tab1_crlTCheckkey and Java_com_labyrinthsys_crltext_Tab1_crlTCheckkey__Ljava_lang_String_2)
                  at com.labyrinthsys.crltext.Tab1.crlTCheckkey(Native Method)
                  at com.labyrinthsys.crltext.Tab1.onClick(Tab1.java:118)
```

I have asked around locally with no luck. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Check the .so file made it into your .apk file.  .apk files are just zip files, so rename it and explore it with your favourite zip explorer.

Comment: Java_com_labyrinthsys_crltext_Tab1_crlTCheckkey is in all four architectures that I have loaded in their libnative-lib.so files. I have a suspicion that the Ljava_lang_String_2 is significant, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very annoying, but I removed the cpp file in question from the build completely, and then brought it in again from scratch, and somehow it now works.

Comment: By from scratch, I mean that I added a new c++ file into the cpp directory, brought in a copy of the basic "stringFromJNI" cpp from another app, got it to run, then brought my code into that and saw that run, then renamed that to my name and it still runs.